# How to delete item from list when list items are lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists:

```
[['Ari', 'male', 'learning'],['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
```

If i wanted to delete the list-item that had 'Ari' in it, how to I remove that whole item so all I would have left is:

```
[['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
```

At the moment I'm trying this:

```
for item in list:
    if 'Ari' in item:
        # Delete item...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension and check for `'Ari'`:

```
print([i for i in list if not 'Ari' in i])
```

Or little different order of keywords:

```
print([i for i in list if 'Ari' not in i])
```

Output:

```
[['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
```

But also, don't name lists `list`, since that will override the actual keyword.

Comment: Is it meant to be 'if not Ari in i' or 'if Ari not in i'

Comment: This would not modify the original list, if that is what the OP (seemingly) wants. Rebind the new list created by the list comprehension, or update in place with slice notation (see my answer for that).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the original list then you can use a list comprehension to create a new list with the desired items removed, and then rebind to the list variable:

```
>>> original = [['Ari', 'male', 'learning'],['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
>>> original = [item for item in original if 'Ari' not in item]
>>> original
[['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
```

This will create a *new* list and then bind the new list to the variable `original`. If the original list is large you can avoid creating a duplicate and update in place:

```
original = [['Ari', 'male', 'learning'],['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
original[:] = [item for item in original if 'Ari' not in item]
>>> original
[['Fran', 'female', 'skilled']]
```

Note the use of slice notation (`[:]`) to update the original list in place.